# Update a row in a table with new values while dodging primary key constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, primary-key

I have 2 tables (let's call them `OriginalTable` and `NewValuesTable`) with several columns. I am going to discuss only about the column in question.

**Pallet ID - Primary key of `OriginalTable`**

`OriginalTable` has around 35000 entries where the `PalletID` value is wrong. My `NewValuesTable` has the right `PalletID` values. Here is my issue:

- Let's take a sample set of the `OriginalTable`

[image]

- These values are all wrong. These need to be replaced with new values from the `NewValuesTable`. Like this:

[image]

- I don't know if the issue is obvious, but let me explain. The highlighted fields are the issue. When I update `21` to `22`, there will be a `PrimaryKey Constraint` related error because it is a duplicate key. Likewise with `34` and `68`. How do I go around this issue?

This is what I thought: Maybe edit the values that have a `Duplicate Key` exception to something like `W**`. For instance, `22` in the `NewValue` table becomes `W22`, `34` becomes `W34`. Add a `W` or something like that. Then update the table with these values. Then update the `OriginalTable`'s `PalletID` field to remove the `W`.

Does that seem like a smart way to go about this? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you updating the rows one at a time? Do the two tables have the same number of rows? Are they are both ordered correctly even though one table needs updating?

Comment: I am updating nearly 35,000 rows using an `update` and `join`. They are ordered, yes. But the `PalletID` field does not have as simple a value as in the question. A typical `PalletID` looks like `H2333431`. The `NewValues` table has 35,000 rows because those are the ones that need changing. The `OriginalTable` has over 100,000 rows, but only the 35,000 rows with wrong `PalletID` are in question.

Comment: If you are updating all the rows at once there should not be any problem.

Comment: Can you mess around with the table structure?

Comment: How do you mean? What part of the structure? Depends on which table you are talking about. if I am messing with `NewValuesTable`, yes. `OriginalTable`, no.

Comment: In your example how do you know that it is the 21 that needs to be updated to 22?

Comment: My `NewValuesTable` has 2 rows. The current value for `PalletID` and what that value needs to be changed to. The second image I have on there is exactly what the `NewValuesTable` looks like

Comment: I was thinking about adding a column with the new values to the table, then changing the primary key to include the original + this column, then update the original primary key column and finally changing the primary key back to a single column and remove the new column.

Comment: Adding a new column to `OriginalTable` is not an option :(

Comment: @ZoharPeled coming back to your comment about how it is not a problem if I am updating all the values at once, IF I use Update and Join to push ALL the new values on to my `OriginalTable`, it wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @Crazy Are you doing updates in a loop or with a cursor? Your update statement should be updating the whole lot in one go, then you shouldn't get the error...

Comment: If you are updating all the rows at once there should be no error.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will look into this a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential issue with updating the rows with a prefix is that, if anything goes wrong you are left with prefixed primary keys since it would be a constraint violation to update them to the new value. You are essentially disabling the constraint when populating it which opens up risks for that population.

I would build an identical empty table (include any constraints) prefixed with something to identify it as a non-production table. Then fill it with the correct values. Once you verify that all the data is correct, change the table names in a single statement. Just make sure there are no running transactions against the original table before updating the names.

Comment: I was really close to doing the prefix method. You actually saved me from that. I have done that once in the past and struggled with it, I completely forgot. That is a good idea. I will see if anyone else has anything useful and if not, probably proceed with yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some SQL to demonstrate how you can update as you wish all in one go. I've included some extra bits of script which should allow you to better test your update SQL on your test environment without ruining your test data:

```
set xact_abort on -- make sure it rolls back if error
go

create table #t1 (link int primary key, id char)
create table #t2 (link int, id char)

insert into #t1 
select 1, 'a' union
select 2, 'b' union
select 3, 'c'

insert into #t2
select 2, 'c' union
select 3, 'd'

BEGIN TRAN

select * from #t1
select * from #t2

select * from #t1 a 
left join #t2 b on a.link = b.link

UPDATE #t1 
set id = b.id
from #t1 a
join #t2 b on a.link = b.link

select * from #t1

ROLLBACK
--commit

drop table #t1
drop table #t2
```